# static member variable in a class

Tags: c++, class, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Why do I have a "undefined reference to `Monitor::count`" error for the following code? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Monitor
{
    static int count;
public:
    void print() { cout << "incident function has been called " << count << " times" << endl; }
    void incident() { cout << "function incident called" << endl; count++; }
};

void callMonitor()
{
    static Monitor fooMonitor;
    fooMonitor.incident();
    fooMonitor.print();
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        callMonitor();
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you *declare* it but do not *define* it. Put the following in one (and **only** one) of your .cpp files:

```
int Monitor::count = 0;
```

Comment: isn't static variable default be initialized to be 0?

Comment: @user673769 : Yes, §8.5/6 guarantees that all static objects will be at a minimum zero-initialized. So, you could shorten the definition to `int Monitor::count;` if you want, but a definition is necessary either way.

Answer (score 2):

You have not defined the static variable `count`.

```
class Monitor
{
     // ...
};

int Monitor::count = 0 ;

// ...
```

Comment: @ildjarn - I am struck at usage of programming terminology :)

Comment: No worries, I'm just pedantic. ;-]