# Singleton pattern c++ error

Tags: c++, singleton, design-patterns

Hi I have implemented a singleton pattern in c++ with the VS2010 and the compiler throw me an  error !!

```
#ifndef __EgEngine__ 
#define __EgEngine__ 1

#include <esUtil.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <EgGpuManager.h>

class   EgEngine
{
public:
    EgEngine();
    static EgGpuManager GetGpuManager();
    ~EgEngine();
    void EgInit();

private:
    EgEngine(const EgEngine &other){};
    EgEngine* operator = (const EgEngine &other)const {};
    static EgGpuManager GpuManager; // Return this !! 
    ESContext esContext;
};

#endif
```

The other class

```
#ifndef __EgGpuManager__
#define __EgGpuManager__ 1

#include <EgBuffer.h>
#include <EgProgram.h>


    class EgGpuManager
    {
    public:
        EgBuffer* GetBuffer();
        EgProgram* GetNewProgram();

    private:
        EgGpuManager();
        ~EgGpuManager();
        EgBuffer buffer;
    };

#endif
```

And when I try to compile I have this error:

```
1>EgEngine.obj : error LNK2001: 
unresolved external symbol "private: static class
EgGpuManager EgEngine::GpuManager" (?GpuManager@EgEngine@@0VEgGpuManager@@A)
```

Help me please and thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [static member variable in a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601051/static-member-variable-in-a-class)

Comment: [Don't use singletons](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/). They are not cool. They are hard to implement correctly, near-impossible in a multi-threaded environment, and even when they're implemented correctly, they still only serve to make your code worse.

Comment: Also, names like `__EgEngine__`  should be avoided. Names containing a double underscore, or which begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation (the compiler and standard library) (Finally, it is common practice to make macros ALL UPPERCASE), so it should be `EGENGINE`, not `EgEngine`.

Answer (score 4):

`static EgGpuManager GpuManager; // Return this !!` this guy has to be instantiated somewhere in your C++ code.

`static` class members have to appear in the global scope, so in the C++ file add:

`EgGpuManager EgEngine::GpuManager`.

By the way, you have a private constructor for `EgGpuManager` class, which will be a problem in this case because it is created by `EgEngine`. You're not implementing the singleton correctly. Use a `static EgGpuManager *EgGpuManager::Get()` method to return an instance, and it will instantiate the class on the first call, then you can do it with a private constructor. Otherwise make them `friend`s.

Comment: Where I need to put the "EgGpuManager EgEngine::GpuManager;" ??

Comment: @Eduard - in one of the C++ files, I would suggest the one with the implementation of the `EgEngine` class.

Comment: I have the same problem.                                                                                                                                     #ifndef __EgEngine__ 
#define __EgEngine__ 1

#include <esUtil.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <EgGpuManager.h>

class EgEngine
{
static EgGpuManager EgEngine::GpuManager;

public:
 EgEngine();
 static EgGpuManager GetGpuManager();
 ~EgEngine();

 void EgInit();

    ESContext esContext;

private:
 EgEngine(const EgEngine &other){};
 EgEngine* operator = (const EgEngine &other)const {};
// static EgGpuManager GpuManager;
};

#endif

Comment: @Eduard you do know what "global scope" means, don't you? Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601051/static-member-variable-in-a-class.

Answer (score 0):

The line "static EgGpuManager GpuManager;" inside the class declaration of EgEngine is only a **declaration**: You're saying that this object will exist somewhere. The linker complains that it did not find the object anywhere. To solve this, place an **instantiation** in one of your source files (in global scope):

```
EgGpuManager EgEngine::GpuManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put the instantiation of the singleton object either in the global scope, as suggested by other answers, or in the implementation of `GetGpuManager()` like this :

```
EgGpuManager& EgEngine::GetGpuManager()
{
  static EgGpuManager GpuManager;
  return GpuManager;
}
```

In this case you need to remove the declaration of GpuManager from the class definition. Also note the & to return a reference, as you certainly don't want to return a copy of the object (that would defeat the purpose of making a singleton). The advantage here is that the object will not be created until `GetGpuManager()` is called for the first time, whereas all statics in global scope are created when the program starts.