# C++ Compiling error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, build, 64-bit

I'm having difficulty getting this to compile. I think the it has to do with the static variables, but I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing. Here is the error message I keep getting:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "Counter::nCounters", referenced from:
>         Counter::Counter(int, int) in main.o
>
> Counter::getNCounters() in main.o
>
> Counter::Counter(int, int) in Counter.o
>
> Counter::getNCounters() in Counter.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef project1_Counter_h
#define project1_Counter_h

class Counter
{
private:
int counter;
int limit;
static int nCounters;

public:
Counter(int, int);
void increment();
void decrement();
int getValue();
static int getNCounters();
};

#endif
```

And here is the .cpp file:

```
#include "Counter.h"

Counter::Counter(int a, int b)
{
counter = a;
limit = b;
nCounters++;
}

void Counter::increment()
{
if (counter < limit)
    counter++;
}

void Counter::decrement()
{
if (counter > 0)
    counter--;
}

int Counter::getValue()
{
return counter;
}

int Counter::getNCounters()
{    
return nCounters;
}
```

And the main.cpp is just a simple Hello World program. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601051/static-member-variable-in-a-class

Comment: Also, I suggest you add a Destructor to your class:  ~Counter() { nCounters--; }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you need to initialize nCounters with a value.

Try adding

```
int Counter::nCounters = 0;
```

somewhere outside the class, or initialize it as:

```
static int nCounters = 0;
```

instead.

Comment: ya, every Static variable should be initialized in the .cpp file. Its better to put all the static variable initializations in the top of your .cpp with a bit comment like `/* -- Static Variables -- */` for the readability.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)