# why I get linker errors when trying to set static variable in a class?

Tags: c++, class, static, undefined-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [static member variable in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601051/static-member-variable-in-a-class)
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

```
class test_struct {
  static int number;
 public:
  static void set() {
    number = 42;
  }
};

int main() {
  test_struct::set();
}
```

The error is:

```
[...]Temp\ccGGxEAz.o:test.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf): undefined reference to `test_struct::number'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Mentioned in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/link-errs-static-data-mems.html

Answer (score 5):

You need to define static member `test_struct::number` in a source code(.cpp), before using it:

```
class test_struct {
  static int number;
 public:
  static void set() {
    number = 42;
  }
};

int test_struct::number = 0;
```

Comment: in a CPP!  not in the header!